# Powershell Extract Number from File Name

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

Files names could be:

```
1234_billing.txt
1234billling.txt
123_billing.txt
123billing.txt
```

How can I extract the only the number in all 4 cases?
I've tried -split and $_.BaseName.Substring() but can't seem to get it correct.

Comment: `Get-ChildItem *.txt | Where{$_.Name -match '\d+'} | ForEach{$Matches[0]}`

Comment: That worked thanks. Follow-up, how do I get the index of the character following the those numbers?

Comment: Figured it out. $Var = $file -match '\d+' | ForEach{Matches[0]} ; $Len = $Var.Length;  $File.Substring(0,$Len);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the filenames are in the array variable `$flist`, the following will do the trick:

```
foreach ($file in $flist) {
    if ($file -match "\d+") {
        $matches.value
    }
}
```

The `-match` operator takes as its right operand a regex pattern; in this case we use the pattern `\d+` to signal any non-zero number of consecutive digits. The operator returns either `$true` or `$false`, and stores the matched substring in `$matches`. There's more about the `-match` operator at [`Get-Help about_Operators`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-5.1), and everyone can use a handy [reference for regular expressions](https://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html).