# Extract only the numbers in file name

Tags: batch-file, batch-rename

I would like to only have the numbers from the file names printed in the .txt file.

```
C:\Users\asd123\Desktop\qwerty - 123.pdf  
C:\Users\asd123\Desktop\qw erty_456.pdf      
C:\Users\asd123\Desktop\qwe rt y789.pdf
```

right now, I use:

```
cd C:\Users\asd123\Desktop\  
for %%a in (*.pdf) do echo %%~na >> C:\Users\asd123\Desktop\file_names.txt
```

what do I need to add to this code in order to have my wishes come ture?

Comment: This is quite easy in PowerShell; if PowerShell is acceptable, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48409026/powershell-extract-number-from-file-name/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED!**

By using *JREPL.BAT* by Dave Benham

and *STRIP.CMD* :

```
cd C:\Users\asd123\Desktop\
@echo off
echo Cleaning out old data
:: Remove old instances of output files in order not to create duplication in the files
del file_name_list_numerics.txt
echo Done!
echo Building file list.
for %%a in (*.pdf) do echo %%~na >> C:\Users\asd123\Desktop\file_names.txt
echo Done!
echo Stripping non-numeric characters from file list.
call jrepl "\D" "" /f file_names.txt /o -
echo Done!
echo Removing empty lines.
For /F "delims=" %%A in (file_names.txt) Do Echo %%A >> C:\Users\asd123\Desktop\file_name_list_numerics.txt
echo Done!
echo Cleaning up temp data.
del file_names.txt
echo Done!
```

Comment: nowadays powershell is available on every PC and should be preferred instead

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
echo | sed -n 's/[^0-9]//gp'
```

Comment: Can't seem to get it to work, the .txt is printed blank.

Comment: there's no sed in Windows, and the echo command prints nothing